# Reinstalled Windows 7. Ethernet not detected anymore

Tags: windows-7, wired-networking, wired

In fact, wireless was not detected at first either for whatever reason, until I pulled out my USB wifi adapter and put it back in. Right now, Local Area Connection does not even show up in Control Panel:

[image: gah]

Not detected in the list of devices either...

[image: oh my!]

But of course the wired connection is there and works, because the Linux partition is doing just fine with it, and the Windows partition was doing well too before I did a clean [re-]install of Windows 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first device under 'Other devices' is an "Ethernet controller". So it is in your list of devices. It is just not yet recognised until you install the right driver.

Right click on that "Ethernet controller", select [properties] and open the tab 'Details'.

Move a few centimeters down and select the property to "Hardware IDs".

You now get a screen with the precise details of your hardware. Vendor, type, revision. It is all there. Use a site such as http://www.pcidatabase.com/ to translate that to human readable format. Then download and install the right driver. Done!

Comment: Oh man, I don't know how I missed that! Many thanks! :)